# "PG::ConnectionBad: SSL error: point is not on curve" in Redshift via Ruby/PG gem using SSL

Tags: openssl, amazon-redshift, pg

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a query on Amazon Redshift in Ruby (via the PG gem) over SSL:

`PG::ConnectionBad: SSL error: point is not on curve`

This error only happens on my local Mac OS X El Capitan machine when trying to connect via SSL. Connecting without SSL works fine. Connecting over SSL on Ubuntu dev server also works fine, which makes me think it's a problem with my local Ruby/OpenSSL setup.

Running Ruby 2.2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2e, pg gem 0.18.2.

I've verified that my Ruby is using the expected version of OpenSSL:

`2.2.2 :001 > OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
 => "OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015"`

I've also verified that the error happens both in Rails/ActiveRecord and in plain old ruby via the Sequel gem.

The pg database config that I'm using sets `sslmode: require`.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please post the exact URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an old version of Postgres.app. Updating it to the latest version and re-installing ruby (via RVM) solved my issue.

Current theory as to why this solve the issue: apparently Postgres.app provides `psql` or something else that is used in the process of compiling the native extensions for the `pg` gem. Whatever Postgres.app provided wasn't good and so the result propagated itself right into the gem and the app itself.